# using sed or awk replace a space by first word

Tags: replace, awk, sed

I have a string like this:

```
qqqqq zzzz aaaa ttttt 77777
```

I need to replace a space by first word. As a result it should look like this:

```
qqqqqzzzzqqqqqaaaaqqqqqtttttqqqqq77777
```

Is it possible to do this using sed or awk?

Comment: why the first space is not replaced by `qqqqq`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this awk one-liner will replace all spaces by the first field.

```
awk '{OFS=$1;$1=$1}7' file
```

will generate:

```
qqqqqqqqqqzzzzqqqqqaaaaqqqqqtttttqqqqq77777
```

#### update:

this line will skip the first space:

```
awk '{x=$1;sub(FS,"\x98");gsub(FS,x);sub("\x98","")}7' file
```

Comment: Nice! I thought on using `awk '{gsub(FS,$1)}1' file` as well.

Comment: @fedorqui your awk line is nice too. however there is slight difference between the two lines. If there are continuous spaces, mine will replace **them** by a  single `$1`, however yours will replace **each of them** by a `$1`.  This is not about right or wrong, just the difference.

Comment: Thanks for answers but this does not work. In my example I have just one occurrence of  qqqqq. Not twice

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/^((\S+)\s+\S+)\s+/\1\2/;ta;s/\s+//' file
```

This replaces the first space(s) following the second word by the first word and then deletes the first space(s).

It might be written:

```
sed -r ':a;s/^((\S+) \S+) /\1\2/;ta;s/ //' file
```